# Updating a EditText after camera take photo

Tags: android, android-camera

i have 2 activity. activity saveData and activity androidCamera

first, i have a form in saveData. when form is already inputed except EditText "Upload Photo". then, i click button camera to take a uri/path image. when `finish()` the camera activity send value uri/path back to SaveData form Activity. the question is how to updating EditText "Upload Photo" in SaveData so when i take picture, the camera send path/uri inside EditText "Upload Photo"?

this is my Activity AndroidCamera

```
    package com.app.databasesample;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean previewing = false;
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

    final int RESULT_SAVEIMAGE = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_camera);
        //

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl 
            = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        Button buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, 
                myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
            }});
    }

    ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }};



    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*Bitmap bitmapPicture 
                = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);  */

            Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

            OutputStream imageFileOS;
            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
                imageFileOS.write(arg0);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();


                Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, 
                        "Image Tersimpan: " + uriTarget.toString(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String sFilename="image";

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("path", uriTarget.toString());

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(AndroidCamera.this, SaveData.class);
            newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
            //
            //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }};

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(previewing){
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null){
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;

    }
}
```

this is my Activity SaveData

```
package com.app.databasesample;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SaveData extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private DataManipulator dh;
    static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
    private  static final boolean TEST_ONLY_NO_FOTO=false;
    private  static final boolean TAKE_FOTO_HIRES=false;
    private Uri outputFileUri;
    File outputFile;
    private String sDirectory="";
    //String sFilename="";
    public static final int SHOW_SUB_ACTIVITY_TAKE_PICTURE=5;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.save);
        View add = findViewById(R.id.Button01add);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        View home = findViewById(R.id.Button01home);
        home.setOnClickListener(this);
        View kamera = findViewById(R.id.kamera);
        kamera.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override 
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
      switch(requestCode) { 
        case (SHOW_SUB_ACTIVITY_TAKE_PICTURE) : { 
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
          String newText = data.getStringExtra("image");
          // TODO Update your TextView.
          //EditText edt = (newText) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
            //edt.setText(uriTarget.toString());
          EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
          edt.setText(newText);

          } 
          break; 
        } 
      } 
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.Button01home:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DatabaseSample.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.Button01add:
            View editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idHandheld);
            View editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namaHama);
            View editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jumlahHama);

            String myEditText1=((TextView) editText1).getText().toString();
            String myEditText2=((TextView) editText2).getText().toString();
            String myEditText3=((TextView) editText3).getText().toString();
            this.dh = new DataManipulator(this);
            this.dh.insert(myEditText1,myEditText2,myEditText3);
            showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
            break;
        case R.id.kamera:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, AndroidCamera.class);
            startActivityForResult(i1,SHOW_SUB_ACTIVITY_TAKE_PICTURE);
            break;
        }
    }

    private void SaveDatas(){
        Date dt=new Date();
        View editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idHandheld);
        View editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namaHama);
        View editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jumlahHama);
        String myEditText4=((TextView) editText4).getText().toString();
        String myEditText5=((TextView) editText5).getText().toString();
        String myEditText6=((TextView) editText6).getText().toString();
        this.dh = new DataManipulator(this);
        this.dh.insert(myEditText4,myEditText5,myEditText6);
        showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
    }//SaveData

    protected final Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch(id){
        case DIALOG_ID:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("input data hama sukses disave | Tambah Input ?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    SaveData.this.finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            dialog = alert;
            break;

             default:
        }
        return dialog;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can update your EditText in onActivityResult of AndroidCamera Activity when activity return from SaveData

Comment: You are already passing uri with bundle `bundle.putString("path", uriTarget.toString());`. So just extract value from bundle in SaveData Activity.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K how to do that?can you give me a sample? im newbie in android

Answer (score 0):

This is you have done in AndroidCamera activity :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("path", uriTarget.toString());

Intent newIntent = new Intent(AndroidCamera.this, SaveData.class);
newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

Change this line

```
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
```

to

```
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Now, Just call this code to your SaveData Activity :

UPDATE :

```
 String imagePath="";
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null){
       imagePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("path");
       your_editText.setText(imagePath);
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: i try to put `String imagePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("path");
your_edittext.setText(imagePath);` inside OnCreate but error nuLLpointerException in line `String imagePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("path");`

Comment: the Edittext worked, but the inputed inside saveData is gone.

Comment: Call `SaveDatas()` before calling this `Intent i1 = new Intent(this, AndroidCamera.class); startActivityForResult(i1,SHOW_SUB_ACTIVITY_TAKE_PICTURE);`.. And get that data from saved data to restore again.

Comment: i call `SaveDatas();` before calling `Intent i1 = new Intent(this, AndroidCamera.class); startActivityForResult(i1,SHOW_SUB_ACTIVITY_TAKE_PICTURE);` but still gone

Comment: first i try `finish()` without `startActivity;` in my pictureTaken the value still inside but the uri/path still not Update

Comment: why you are using custom preview to capture image? It will be easy to call inbuilt camera preview.

Comment: check this link to get image uri by calling device camera and capture image : [http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2011/08/get-camera-capture-image-path-in.html?showComment=1326875502426#c8966275498046222488]

Comment: because this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505662/camera-inside-app-force-close-data-null-when-i-try-in-different-device] i have a problem before. about device.

Comment: this device make me crazy.

Comment: how about send a value input data to CameraActivity, save and send it again to SaveData with uri. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Write below line before `setContentView(R.layout.save);` in `onCreate()` method of SaveData Activity, it will solve your problem.

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
```

Comment: a try but error NPE in line `String param1 = bundle.getString("path");` @Dipak Keshariya

Comment: the logcat `12-07 16:49:54.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5240): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-07 16:49:54.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5240):     at com.app.databasesample.SaveData.onCreate(SaveData.java:44)
12-07 16:49:54.632: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5240):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
`

Comment: update this code line. String newText = data.getData(); this will give you url of image.

Comment: i update in oncreate but the 'data' cannot be resolved `data.getData();`

Comment: @Alexbelek Don't write above code line in onCreate(), write this line instead of this code line. String newText = data.getStringExtra("image");

Comment: @Alexbelek Then write this line String newText = String.valueOf(data.getData()); instead of my above line.

Comment: Still NPE  `databasesample.SaveData.onCreate(SaveData.java:44)`

Answer (score 0):

You should call the method "setResult" to submit your result to the calling Activity and then check the result in "onResume".
But a general hint for you. In Android you can leverage the Intent system for the benefit of the user. One example would be to let the user choose his camera app to take the picture instead of writing your own activity for this. This saves you a lot of time and the user is happy he can use the specific camera app which suits his needs and that he hunted down for hours and paid for it.